# Particular solution of the non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we have the non-homogeneous differential equation $$ay''(x)+by'(x)+cy(x)=f(x)$$ and the non-homogeneous term $f(x)$ is of the form $d_1e^{mx}$ we know that the particular solution is $$y_p=d_2x^ke^{mx}$$ where $k$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $w=m$.

When we have the non-homogeneous differential equation $$ay''(x)+by'(x)+cy(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n s_i e^{r_ix}$$ will the particular solution be $$y_p=x^k\sum_{i=1}^n h_ie^{r_ix}$$ ?

Comment: They are called particular solutions, not partial solutions.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will edit it... @JuliánAguirre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular solution will be of the form
$$
y_p=\sum_{i=1}^nh_i\,x^{k_i}e^{r_ix}
$$
where $k_i$ is the multiplicity of $r_i$.

Comment: The characteristic equation of the corresponding homogeneous problem is $$a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$$ The discriminant is $$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$ and then we have $$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ So that the solution contains only exponentials, we want that $b^2-4ac \neq 0$, right? That means that $k_i=0, \forall i$, or not?

Comment: Or is what I said wrong?

Comment: The particular solution contains only exponentials because the right hand side of the equation contains only exponentials. The solution of the homogeneous equation may contain sines and cosines.

Comment: But the sines and cosines can also be written as exponentials, right? But when we want that $b^2-4ac \neq 0$ the multiplicity of each eigenvalue is $0$, so the solution contains only exponentials and not a combination with polynomials. Is this correct?

Comment: The multiplicity of each root of the characteristic equation (what you call eigenvalue) is $1$ in that case. If $r_i$ is complex and is a solution of the characteristic equation, you will have terms of the form $x\,e^{r_ix}$.

Comment: So we want that $b^2-4ac \neq 0$ and $r_i \neq \lambda_j, \forall i, j$ so that the solution contains only exponentials and not a combination with polynomials, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-) $$$$ Could you maybe take also a look at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500741/solutions-of-a-linear-differential-equation-of-second-order ?