# Solutions of a linear differential equation of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to check if a linear differential equation of second order has a solution in the ring $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$.

We define $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ as the set of expresions $$\alpha=\alpha_1 e^{\mu_i x}+\dots \alpha_N e^{\mu_N x}$$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mu_i \in \mathbb{C}$. (The $\mu_i$'s are pairwise distinct.)

I have done the following:

The general linear differential equation is $$ay''(x)+by'(x)+cy(x)=f(x) \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

The corresponding homogeneous problem is $$ay''(x)+by'(x)+cy(x)=0$$ The characteristic equation is $$am^2+bm+c=0 \\ \Delta=b^2-4ac \\ m_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, a \neq 0$$

There is a solution in $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ if $b^2-4ac \neq 0$, since then the solution of the homogeneous problem is given by the formula $$y_H(x)=c_1e^{m_1 x}+c_2e^{m_2 x}$$

Since $f(x)$ is of the form $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e^{\mu_i x}}$ the particular solution of the non-homogeneous differential equation is $\displaystyle{y_p=\sum_{i=1}^n h_ix^{k_i}e^{\mu_ix}}$, where $k_i$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\mu_i$.

Substituting this at $(*)$ we get $$a\sum_{i=1}^n h_i \left [k_i(k_i-1)x^{k_i-2}+\mu_ik_ix^{k_i}k_ix^{k_i-1}+\mu_ix^{k_i}\right ]e^{\mu_ix} +b\sum_{i=1}^n h_i\left [k_ix^{k_i-1}+\mu_ix^{k_i}\right ]e^{\mu_ix}+c\sum_{i=1}^n h_ix^{k_i}e^{\mu_ix}=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e^{\mu_i x}$$

It must stand $$h_i \left [a\left [k_i(k_i-1)x^{k_i-2}+\mu_ik_ix^{k_i}k_ix^{k_i-1}+\mu_ix^{k_i}\right ]+b\left [k_ix^{k_i-1}+\mu_ix^{k_i}\right ]+cx^{k_i} \right ]=\alpha_i$$

Is this correct so far?

So does the differential equation have a solution in this ring only if the equation $$h_i \left [a\left [k_i(k_i-1)x^{k_i-2}+\mu_ik_ix^{k_i}k_ix^{k_i-1}+\mu_ix^{k_i}\right ]+b\left [k_ix^{k_i-1}+\mu_ix^{k_i}\right ]+cx^{k_i} \right ]=\alpha_i$$ is solvable?

Comment: In the formula for $y_p$ you must use $\mu_i$, not $r_i$.

Comment: I edited it... Is everything else correct so far? @JuliánAguirre

Comment: In order to have all solutions in $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ you need two things: 1) All roots of the characteristic equation are simple; for second order equations this means that the discriminant is not zero. 2) The exponents of the exponentials on the right hand side are not roots of the characteristic equations, that is, $k_i=0$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-) @JuliánAguirre Could you take also a look at my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502307/linear-differential-equations-with-constants-coefficients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need constant coefficient for your approach. I do not see what you can do for non-constant coefficients.

I do not know why you make such a long computation for the inhomogeneity. Obviously you have to exclude resonance to avoid polynomial factors. In the resonance case, i.e., when $\mu_i>0$, you will always get the polynomial factor.

Comment: Yes, $a,b,c$ are constants. Could you explain to me further your second paragraph?

Comment: Do you mean if the multiplicity of the eigenalues is $0$ ?

Comment: The  exponential factors on the right, in $f(x)$, should not be roots of the characteristic polynomial, i.e., be not in resonance. So yes.

Comment: So that the general solution of the differential equation is in the ring $\text{EXP}(\mathbb{C})$ it must stand that $$b^2-4ac \neq 0 \ \ \land \ \ \mu_i \neq \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \forall i$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Of course it gets more complicated for higher orders, see "discriminant" (as the determinant of some Sylvester or Bezout matrix).

Comment: I tried to look what happens at the case of a linear differential equation of order $m$ in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$. Could you take at it? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502307/linear-differential-equations-of-higher-order